# How to nest a list based on increasing sequences and ignore left overlapping ranges

Tags: python, algorithm, math

This is my input

```
mylist = [2, 7, 8, 11, 7, 9, 10, 15, 22, 30, 32]
```

- from 2 to 11, it's increasing, so we need to grab the min max `[2, 11]`
- from 7 to 10  it's increasing, but we need to ignore it because the range
  (7 to 10) is inluded in the first grabed list
- from 15 to 32, it's increasing, so we need to grab the min max: `[15, 32]`

the final list should be : `[[2, 11], [15, 32]]`

I tried something like below but it does not :

```
final = []
mi = mylist[0]
ma = mylist[1]

for i, j in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]):

    if i < j:
        ma = j
    elif i > j:
        mi = i
        continue
            
    elif mi == ma:
        continue
    final.append([mi, ma])
```

**update:**

Let me add more scenarios :

- for `[5, 8, 10, 3, 4, 5, 7]` we should get `[[5,10]]` because even if `[3, 7]` is overlapping with `[5, 10]`, the start of `[3, 7]` is behind `[5, 10]`
- for `[5, 8, 10, 8, 9, 12]` we should get `[[5,12]]` which is `[5,10] ∪ [8, 12]` because `[8, 12]` is overlapping with `[5, 10]` from the right (ahead of it)
- for `[1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` we should get `[[1, 5]]` because from 4 to 1 it is a decreasing sequence, so we have to ignore it

**I'm not necessarily looking for a Python code. I just need the algorithm or the correct way to approach this problem.**

Comment: You *really* need to explain the logic a lot better on this question.

Comment: What to do if you find 5..10 interval, then 3..7 or 8..12 one?

Comment: What's the expected result for `[3,2,1]`?  `[3,2,4]`?

Comment: @MBo, then we make [5, 10] for the first one and [5, 12] for the second.

Comment: @VERBOSE It is necessary to define clear rules. Why 3..7 don't influence on result, but 8..12 is joined. Perhaps **real** problem description might help to understand the logic.

Comment: Sorry @MBo, give me two seconds, I will update the post to clarify the logic more.

Comment: And what about decreasing runs  1 3 5 4 3 2 1 ?

Comment: I added three more example, including your last one.

Comment: @VERBOSE Based on the expected output for `[5, 8, 10, 8, 9, 12]` shouldn't the original case `[2, 7, 8, 11, 7, 9, 10, 15, 22, 30, 32]` output be `[[2,32]]` because `[2,11] ∪ [7, 32] = [2,32]`?

Comment: I'm with tax evader on the original [2, 7, 8, 11, 7, 9, 10, 15, 22, 30, 32] case. Consolidating [] with [2, 11]
  Gives: [[2, 11]]
Consolidating [[2, 11]] with [9, 32]
  Gives: [[2, 32]]

Comment: You have given no feedback on the current answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think zipping the array makes sense. You could solve this problem by keeping track of min and max indices of the local sequences by iterating through the array

```
mylist = [2, 7, 8, 11, 7, 9, 10, 15, 22, 30, 32]

final = []

minIndex = -1 
maxIndex = -1 
maxValue = -1 * float('inf') 

for i in range(0, len(mylist)):
    if minIndex == -1 and mylist[i] > maxValue:
        maxValue = mylist[i]
        minIndex = i
        maxIndex = i
    
    if i > 0:
        if mylist[i - 1] >= mylist[i]:
            final.append([mylist[minIndex], mylist[maxIndex]])
            minIndex = -1
            maxIndex = -1
        else:
            maxIndex += 1
            maxValue = max(maxValue, mylist[i])

if minIndex != -1:
    final.append([mylist[minIndex], mylist[min(maxIndex, len(mylist) - 1)]])

print(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

Task split into two:

1. Finding rising ranges.
2. Consolidating *all* found ranges. (Note if you only want to consolidate the newly found range with the single Null or only the previous, single range found then that is  different).

I have also added `_info` to guide you through the algorithm.

**Code**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
How to nest a list based on increasing sequences
and ignore left overlapping ranges

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77161209/how-to-nest-a-list-based-on-increasing-sequences-and-ignore-left-overlapping-ran


Created on Sat Sep 23 11:07:48 2023

@author: paddy3118
"""


def check_n_add(rngs: list[list[int]],
                this: list[int],
                _info: bool=False) -> None:
    "range consolidation, in-place"
    if _info:
        print(f"  Consolidating {rngs} with {this}")
    t0, t1 = this
    to_keep = True
    for rng in rngs:
        r0, r1 = rng
        if r0 <= t0 <= r1:
            # overlaps
            to_keep = False  # covere-by or extends another
            if t1 > r1:
                # extend
                rng[1] = t1
    if to_keep:
        rngs.append(this)
    if _info:
        print(f"    Gives: {rngs}")


def increasing_subrange_consolidation(data: list[int],
                                      _info: bool=True) -> list[list[int]]:
    if _info:
        print(f"Input: {data}")
    data.append(data[-1] - 1)  # sentinel
    last = data[0]
    ranges = []
    rng = []
    for n in data:
        if n >= last:
            # increasing
            if not rng:
                rng = [last, n]
            else:
                rng[1] = n
        else:
            # decreasing
            if rng and rng[0] < rng[1]:
                check_n_add(ranges, rng, _info)
            rng = []
        last = n

    if _info:
        print(f"Answer: {ranges}\n")
    return ranges

for mylist in [[2, 7, 8, 11, 7, 9, 10, 15, 22, 30, 32],
               [5, 8, 10, 3, 4, 5, 7],
               [5, 8, 10, 8, 9, 12],
               [1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]:
    increasing_subrange_consolidation(mylist, _info=True)
```

**Output**

```
Input: [2, 7, 8, 11, 7, 9, 10, 15, 22, 30, 32]
  Consolidating [] with [2, 11]
    Gives: [[2, 11]]
  Consolidating [[2, 11]] with [7, 32]
    Gives: [[2, 32]]
Answer: [[2, 32]]

Input: [5, 8, 10, 3, 4, 5, 7]
  Consolidating [] with [5, 10]
    Gives: [[5, 10]]
  Consolidating [[5, 10]] with [3, 7]
    Gives: [[5, 10], [3, 7]]
Answer: [[5, 10], [3, 7]]

Input: [5, 8, 10, 8, 9, 12]
  Consolidating [] with [5, 10]
    Gives: [[5, 10]]
  Consolidating [[5, 10]] with [8, 12]
    Gives: [[5, 12]]
Answer: [[5, 12]]

Input: [1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  Consolidating [] with [1, 5]
    Gives: [[1, 5]]
Answer: [[1, 5]]
```