# How to pad 0s to garantee same length while iterating over two lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My inputs are :

```
x = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D']
y = [ 4 ,  3 ,  5 ,  9 ,  1 ,  6 ,  2 ]
```

And I'm just trying to make this dictionary.

```
{'A': [4, 0, 0], 'B': [3, 5, 0], 'C': [9, 0, 0], 'D': [1, 6, 2]}
```

The logic : we collect the values and pad `0` x times to reach a length equal to the max length of letters (`3` here for `D`).

I made the code below but I got a different result :

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(x)
max_length = c.most_common()[0][-1]

my_dict = {}
for ix, iy in zip(x,y):
    my_dict[ix] = [iy] + [0 for _ in range(max_length-1)]
    
{'A': [4, 0, 0], 'B': [5, 0, 0], 'C': [9, 0, 0], 'D': [2, 0, 0]}
```

Can you tell what's wrong with it please ?

Comment: Look at this line: `my_dict[ix] = [iy] + [0 for _ in range(max_length-1)]`. If `my_dict` already contains key `ix`, what do you think happens to the existing value for that key?

Comment: We're not here to do your debugging for you, but I'm happy to point you in the right direction. Check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: You should give feedback on past questions. Otherwise it seems as if your just a taker.

Comment: Hi @Paddy3118, you're a bit severe but thanks for the reminder! I'll be sure to give feedback on my past question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77161209/how-to-nest-a-list-based-on-increasing-sequences-and-ignore-left-overlapping-ran. I just didn't find the energy to do that since this one has got many downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

x = ["A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D"]
y = [4, 3, 5, 9, 1, 6, 2]

vals = {}
for vx, vy in zip(x, y):
    vals.setdefault(vx, []).append(vy)

out = dict(zip(vals, map(list, zip(*zip_longest(*vals.values(), fillvalue=0)))))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'A': [4, 0, 0], 'B': [3, 5, 0], 'C': [9, 0, 0], 'D': [1, 6, 2]}
```

Comment: If I'm following this right, the double-zip is a [transpose](/q/6473679/4518341), right?

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, `zip(*iters)` is transposing operation.

Comment: Donnow how you envisioned the last line but I like it. Thanks @AndrejKesely.

Answer (score 2):

You have all the building blocks there, but I think you might be attempting to much at once. I would start with three distinct steps:

1. build the base result
2. find the length of the longest result
3. pad each base result to the length of the longest

```py
x = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D']
y = [ 4 ,  3 ,  5 ,  9 ,  1 ,  6 ,  2 ]

results = {}
for key, value in zip(x, y):
    results.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

longest_value = max(len(value) for value in results.values())

for value in results.values():
    value.extend([0] * (longest_value - len(value)))

print(results)
```

That should give you:

```
{'A': [4, 0, 0], 'B': [3, 5, 0], 'C': [9, 0, 0], 'D': [1, 6, 2]}
```